# Need to check whether a list of strings can form a particular word, where we can use the items in the list can be used only once or we don't use

Tags: java, string, recursion, data-structures

**Input**

word = foobarbaz

Contents of List of Strings
foob
foo
ba
ba
r
z

**Output**

true

---

**TEST CASE 2**
Input
word = foobarbaz

Contents of List of Strings
foo
fooz
ba
r
z

**Output**

false

---

We can assume len(word) >=1 and size(content of list of strings) >= 1

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TilePossibilties {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "foobarbaz";

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayList.add("foob");
    arrayList.add("foo");
    arrayList.add("ba");
    arrayList.add("r");
    arrayList.add("z");

    System.out.println(check(word, arrayList));

}

private static boolean check(String word,ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

    return isOkay(arrayList, word, "");
}

private static boolean isOkay(ArrayList<String> arrayList, String word, String candidate) {

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        String test = candidate + arrayList.get(i);

        if(test.equals(word)) {
            return true;
        }

        if(word.startsWith(test)) {
            boolean tempResult = isOkay(arrayList, word, test);
            if(tempResult) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        test = candidate;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What part is not working?

Answer (score 1):

We're not a homework factory. I'll point out however that this is a problem that's easier to think about as a recursion. In pseudocode:

```
match(word, set):
  for each s in set:
    if word == s 
      or word starts with s and match(word with s prefix removed, set - s):
        return true;
  return false;
```